# Issue while running java -jar "Spring Application"

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application that i built on Eclipse IDE. When i am running the main class (Run as Java Application) from IDE . It's working fine & my server is getting started.

But the issue is - When i am creating runnable jar from the IDE (packaging all the libraries in generated jar) & then trying to run this jar through command prompt(java -jar -Dfilepath="/properties_file_path xyz.jar"). It's giving me the issue i.e. "Exception while starting the server No qualifying bean of type [com.sgi.main.NettyServer] is defined"

So, I am confuse why it's working with IDE but not working through java -jar command.

Please help me, your help will be appreciable.

Thanks & Regards,
Sumit

Comment: Is it a `Maven` or `Gradle` project?

Comment: How do you build the JAR? Because it looks like your dependencies are not included in the compiled JAR

Comment: Isn't it `java -jar -Dfilepath="/properties_file_path" xyz.jar`?

Comment: @Kiltek --It is a maven project

Comment: @SvenHakvoort -- I have extracted the jar & checked it , all the jar was there

Comment: @talex -- same command i am running

Comment: You should be using maven or Gradle to create a runnable jar for spring boot. Simply exporting it from eclipse and throwing the jars in a random location is not the way to go.

Comment: In your Eclipse IDE: Open "Run Configurations", under "Java Application" search for your project and look through the tabs to find command line arguments, Classpath settings and JRE settings. Adapt your jar command accordingly. Or alernatively: use Mavens "Fat Jar" capabilites to create a Jar file including all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks everyone . Now it's working , i made it "fat/uber jar" using maven-shade-plugin :)